# No algpseudocode-package in TeXstudio

Tags: algorithms

I am using TeXstudio for writing my thesis. I am tying to use the `algpseudocode`-package, but it says that the package isn't found. Here is the screenshot of the error that I am getting:

[image: Error that I am getting]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: have you installed any of the following: TeX Live? MiKTeX?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TeXstudio. It is only your editor, while the package is missing in the TeX distribution (e.g. TeX Live, MacTeX, MikTeX)

Comment: The distribution package, which contains `algpseudocode.sty`, is called `algorithmicx` both in MiKTeX and in TeX Live.

Comment: I have installed TexWorks...Isn't that sufficient ?

Comment: Should I download Tex Live ? I have a follow up question...How am I able to use Latex even though I haven't downloaded Tex Live or Miktex ?

Comment: @naphaneal I have downloaded tex live. I also checked if I have algorithmicx package. It says that the package already exists. However, it is still showing in Tex Studio that the package is not found. I would like to mention that I am using Latex for the last one week now. So I don't know the obvious stuff as well. Could you please explain in a little detailed manner. That would be really helpful.

Comment: TeXworks, TeXstudio and friends are just editors. you need a (La)TeX compiler. As for TeXstudio you need to check, if the commands are fully configured (see `Option` -> `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Commands`) . It might be necessary to reinstall TeXstudio, if a restart fails. also try to run `latex` or `pdflatex` from commandline. as you did not provide a MWE or your system specs I can only give general pointers

Comment: For me this fixed the issue:
    sudo tlmgr install algpseudocode